# RC Circuit with exponential input - Laplace

Tags: laplace-transform

I have a given RC-circuit with

$$RC*\frac{dv(t)}{dt}+v(t) = v_{0}*u(t)$$

and I'm looking for the **output waveform and the 50% delay** with an exponential input given by

$$v(t) = v_{0}*\left(1-e^{-\frac{t}{T}}\right)$$

where \$T\$ is a time constant, using Laplace.

What I've done so far is finding the output wave form:

$$v(t)=v_{0}\left(1-e^\frac{-t}{RC}+\frac{T}{RC-T}*e^\frac{-t}{T}-\frac{T}{RC-T}*e^\frac{-t}{RC}\right)$$

**1.) Is that correct? Is it possible to simplify it even more?**

Next I've tried to compute the 50% delay:

$$v(t)=0.5*v_{0}$$

$$0.5=\left(1-e^\frac{-t}{RC}+\frac{T}{RC-T}*e^\frac{-t}{T}-\frac{T}{RC-T}*e^\frac{-t}{RC}\right)$$

leading to

$$\frac{RC}{2T}-0.5 = e^\frac{-t}{T}-\frac{RC}{T}*e^\frac{-t}{RC}$$

**2.) Is that correct? How can I solve for t?**

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you required to get a Laplace transform representation of the original differential equation or some way further down the analysis? Also the term '50% delay' is new to me - do you mean the time taken for the step response to reach 50% of its final value?

Comment: I need to find the output voltage waveform of the given RC-circuit (eq. 1) with the input voltage (eq. 2) by using Laplace. Equation 3 is what I get by using Laplace, but I'm not sure if this is right.

Then I need to calculate the 50% delay, which is, as you said, the time that the output signal needs to reach 50% of the input signal. Basically I need to solve the last equation for t, but I don't understand how.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your analysis is correct. As below with a slightly simpler final expression

LT of the RHS of eq 1 is: Vo[1/s - T/(s+T)] = Vo/s(1+Ts)

LT of the LHS of eq 1 is: V(1+RCs)

Combining: V(1+RCs) = Vo/s(1+Ts), giving V = Vo/s(1+Ts)(1+RCs)

Partial fractions and inverse LT:

v(t) = Vo{1 + RC/(T-RC).e^(-t/RC) - T/(T-RC).e^(-t/T)}